# Does XPC require sandboxing for MAS

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, xpc

I have a sandboxed app.

This app has an XPC service which is not sandboxed.

Does the XPC service need to be sandboxed as well for me to be able to submit to the Mac App Store?

Comment: I haven't submitted yet.  I think you should reopen this question.

Comment: Nevermind, discovered the service does indeed have to be sandboxed (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/growl-development/RPbSKqxrZ7w/n3Rua2YeKosJ).  Still don't agree with it being closed though.  It's helpful information.

Comment: That message you linked is a mess.  I'll reopen the question if you take a few moments to compose a clear, complete answer to your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every binary, including XPC components, that's part of a Mac App Store submission [must be sandboxed](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/checklist/). However the entitlements for each binary can (and probably should, if the app is well-factored) be different: XPC is designed to support that case.